# Guessing what is the client browser

Tags: java, user-agent

I got the following information using request.getHeader("User-Agent") method inside a Servlet:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10

Actually what is the client browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [Chrome 8.0.552](http://www.google.com/chrome).

This website may be useful for future consultations: http://user-agent-string.info. Paste the UA string there and click *Analyze*. They have even a [XML-RPC webservice](http://user-agent-string.info/api/xmlrpc-java-example).

Comment: Really a SMART answer. Thank you.